# How to upload HTML to GDocs API "as is"?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have generated a HTML document and uploaded it to GDocs using the API. But Google docs keeps messing up the HTML (adding extra whitespace, using another font-family and so on).

How do I tell the API not to mess with my uploaded HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it saved as pure HTML, make sure you are not passing `convert=true` (Drive API) or pass `convert=false` (Docs List API v3) which will tell Drive to just treat it as a binary file. Downside is that you will not be able to edit the file in Google Docs, but it will remain byte-for-byte identical.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately I do want to edit the file. Is there some documentation available regarding formatting your HTML file which Google Drive understands to convert elements as paragraphs, header, footer and such? In other words, do you have documentation about how Google Drive interprets your HTML during conversion?

Comment: To clarify this case a bit more, the uploaded HTML document actually contains HTML of a Google document retrieved via the API itself. It's altered just a little bit. Does Google Drive recognize HTML code compliant with "converted HTML documents"?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Paul. Unfortunately there is no pure round-trip fidelity on HTML, even our own HTML. Sorry!

Comment: No need to apologize, Ali. Two last questions (I hope :P) Can I use another format with which the problem can be solved? How would you solve this problem?

Comment: I think PDF is our best fidelity. I'm not sure I have a good solution.